# How to auto resize the margin_left and margin_right sizes based on screen size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image]

1>How i see the screen like this, at all different screen sizes?
2>what are the steps i have to follow for that?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sridhar.textviewautosize.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:text="Hello World I am Checking AutoFill Text View is working or not for different screens" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please check this code and tell me how to i auto resize that margin left and margin right attributes based on screen sizes for small,medium, large and xlarge.

Comment: Have you tried using ConstraintLayout?

Comment: If I use the constraintLayout, is this possible to support for different screen sizes? @Hawk

Comment: What do you mean by autofit?

Comment: autofit means auto adjusting based on different screen sizes and resolutions @dazza5000

Comment: @ballu I am not totally sure what you want, but in ConstraintLayout, you can specify the margins and graphically draw "arrows" in the Design view to match other elements' center or edge. Then AFAIK it dynamically resizes the element according to the given constraints on screens of any size. If you think this will help you, I can post it as an answer. Try exploring more on these sites:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#0
and https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the hdpi,xhdpi,etc. It will cover all the phone size. set the dimensions.xml inside resource.

For example:
res/values-hdpi/dimensions.xml, res/values-xhdpi/dimensions.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">20dp</dimen>
```

Comment: how do i apply to the xml file pls give me clarity on this? please

Comment: How do i apply that resource file to my xml file please tell me @Nilesh patel

Comment: inside resource folder, make folders name, examples:values-hdpi, values-xhdpi, values-mdpi.   makes xml with name dimens.xml.. give this refresh to your TextView.

Answer (score 2):

You should define margin in different `values` folder as below:

[image]

If you need to support more screen size, you can add as many `sw` folder as you want. You can calculate the `sw dp` from the below image:

[image]

-> nexus 4: 768/2 = 384dp, Nexus 5: 1080/3 =360, Pixel 2: 1080 * 160/420 = 410dp.

Comment: Is there any simple procedure like we followed for text size auto fill for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to get your screen size

```
public void get_screen_size(){

        int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;


        switch(screenSize) {
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Extra Large Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Large Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Normal Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Small Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Screen size is not xlarge, large, normal or small", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

And then depending in the actual screen size, apply the margins you think are needed **programmatically**.

However, i suggest you avoid using margins alltogether and instead find another solution perhaps using weights so that it will work on any screen.

The best solution ofcourse is to follow what android suggests for supporting diferrent screen sizes as can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html